# Maintaining HttpSession attributes in JSF based project

Tags: jsf, httpsession

Recently I was working on project which is JSF based and I am new to it. Now I needed to save some object within HttpSession. So below was my approach.

**Approach 1:**

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest =(HttpServletRequest)facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();

HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();

if(session.getAttribute("userResources") != null){
     userResources = session.getAttribute("userResources");
  }
else{
  //call method to calculate userResources//
  session.setAttribute("userResource",userResources);
}
```

Problem with this approach:

If first person logs in and his userResources are calculated and set as session attribute.
Now if he logs out but does not close browser and second user logs in using same browser then userResources of first person are available to second user while userResources of second person should have been calculated and set anew.

**Approach 2:**

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

Map<String,Object> sessionMap = facesContext.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();

if(sessionMap.get("userResources") != null){
     userResources = sessionMap.get("userResources");
  }
else{
  //call method to calculate userResources//
  sessionMap.put("userResource",userResources);
}
```

In this approach everything works fine:

If first person logs in then his userResources are calculated and put in sessionMap.
Now if he logs out but does not close browser and second user logs in using same browser then userResources of second person are calculated afresh and put in sessionMap.

But I do not understand why my first approach is failing. I didn't do anything special I believe in second approach.
Is there a difference between setting attributes using SessionMap and HttpSession?

Comment: Can you post the code that close session? How you can be sure that the user is "closing" the session? It seems to be a problem with logout mechanism

Comment: Don't do it this way. This is the old pure servlet way. Read a decent JSF tutorial (start at http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) and you'll encounter @SessionScoped annotations... no manual hassling like this needed!